# Android app icon vs language

Tags: android

I'm building a hello world android app.

When I setup the device in "English" language, then I start my app, I can see an icon near my app name.
But when I switch to "French" language, the icon disappears (I still can see my app name but not the icon).

In my manifest.xml : android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

In all drawable-*dpi folders, there is my ic_launcher.png file

Can't see what's wrong ..

Thanks for your help.
Vincent.

Edit : content of values-fr\styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you sure non of the drawable folder names has "en" somewhere ?

Comment: See http://postimg.org/image/kgjj4yu6n/

Comment: I see that have some custom values for "fr", can you paste in values-fr\styles.xml  ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited my post to add values-fr\styles.xml content

Comment: I have no other ideas.

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to Themes, since the bar where I see the app name is larger in English than in French.

But I don't understand anything to Android themes :(

Comment: You can try removing styles.xml and dimens.xml from values-fr

Comment: It worked !
Thank you so much, been working on it for days ..
However, I doubled check and both dimens.xml and styles.xml files were exactly the same from values\ folder ...